# How to solve "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object"

Tags: python, dataframe

I wanted to add a new column to a dataframe and put a list into each cell of this new column. But finally it returned a TypeError  `cannot unpack non-iterable int object`.

Below is my code:

```
x['Leaking pipe']=0
x['Leaking pipe']=x['Leaking pipe'].astype('object')
for i,j in x.index:
    x.at[(i,j),'Leaking pipe']=['p31','p158','p183','p232','p257','p369','p427','p461','p538','p628','p654','p673','p810','p866']
x
```

Would appreciate a lot if any advices and helps.

X dataframe is shown below:

```
Timestamp  n1        n4          n31      ......    p235      PUMP_1
0.000000   28.92     33.87       37.13    ......    83.93     44.4
0.083333   28.94     33.89       37.16    ......    76.34     44.6
...
23.916667  28.63     33.66       36.99    ......    86.91     44.4
```

Comment: Please provide the full error message, including the complete stack trace

Comment: Would also benefit from having a code example that runs and reproduces the error.

Comment: It will be best to provide the full error message so we can know what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Without all details i have a guess which is displayed in the example below. In your code above, `x.index` is probably an iterable containing integers (e.g. a list), and when you loop with `for i,j in x.index` you are in fact attempting to unpack an integer from x.index which isn't possible, causing the error to occur.

```py
class MyClass:
    index = [15, 16, 17]

x = MyClass()

for i, j in x.index:
    pass

# This would throw TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
# because you can't unpack the int with value 15 (or any other int) 
# into the two variables i and j
```

this is the same as trying to run the code `x, y = 15`

So, basically you would need to revise the loop and see from which iterable you are expecting the variables i and j, but due to lack of more information in the question, i can't be more specific than that.